# Error 406 while implementing JSON based REST API using Spring 4.1

Tags: spring-mvc

I am implementing few REST APIs using Spring 4.1 framework. While trying to access the REST API from browser, I am getting the following error:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

I have read other answers and I am able to infer that I need to add correct Jackson libraries and enable MVC configuration in spring properly. I think I am doing both of these, but the issue is still there. Apart from the spring JARs, I have added the following Jackson libraries:

```
jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar jackson-core-2.4.2.jar jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
```

My Configuration class looks like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setCache(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;

    }
}
```

And the request class is simply:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/example", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*", produces="application/json")
    public Account example() {
        //Just return the default data
        return new Account();
    }
}
```

Please Help. I am not able to understand, what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.` What `Accept` headers are you sending?

Comment: How can I find that? I am sending this header : headers="Accept=*/*"

Comment: How do you send your request? Also, don't mix Jackson version. Use 2. That's it.

Comment: I have tried with only Jackson version 2. There is no difference. I send request using browser like localhost:8080/myservlet/example

Comment: Open up your browser's network console and check the headers. Is `Accept=*/*` really there?

Comment: This is the request: Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6

Comment: Ah, please edit your question with that information. It is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration

```
headers="Accept=*/*"
```

basically states that any `Accept` header is good.

Your request contains

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8
```

Because your method is within a `@RestController`, Spring will use a `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to handle your method's return value. Part of that process is choosing an acceptable representation. Since your `*/*` matches `text/html`, `text/html` will be chosen as the acceptable representation.

Spring will then try to find an `HttpMessageConverter` that can convert your return value to `text/html`. It will not find one and will therefore fail.

Either remove the `headers` attribute altogether or change it to `Accept=application/json` which will be matched by the request's `*/*`.

Comment: I removed the headers attribute but it does not make any difference. The error is still same.

Comment: @Aarkan Did you rebuild after you removed it? I works fine for me. Turn your logs to DEBUG level and check what Spring spits out.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks a lot. I cross checked the build and renamed the endpoint but result is still same, I am getting the same error. How can I change the logging level for Spring?

Comment: @Aarkan You'll need to get slf4j with log4j or logback configured.